# How to get date time stamp in android?

Tags: android

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Currently i can use this code to get time in dd/mm/yyyy format.

what i would like to get is date and time with no formatting..so for

15/04/2011 12:00:00
i want :

15042011120000

?

Comment: it is not timestamp, it's just date format

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
String format = s.format(new Date());
```

Comment: How can I get milli-seconds using this?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol "date" ? :/ which package to import please ?

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own `DateFormat` object (store it statically) and use that in the same way:

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();      
String myfrmt = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) + c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```